# Add Layer in raster in R programming

Tags: r, raster

I am trying to add names from raster layer to existing raster brick and I am facing issue there . here's my code for reference.

```
file <- (path)/b_file.grd
file <- addLayer(file, r_names)
```

**r_names are raster names which is raster layer and file is raster brick .**

below error I am getting.
error is compare raster(c(x,rasters) : different extent .

Comment: what do you mean with "add names"? Also see `?addLayer` (its first argument is a Raster object, not a character value.

Comment: thank you for help @RobertHijmans , I was bit confused but now it worked out .